# Sum of int from list of object

Tags: java, java-8

I have a class as following

```
class Account{
    String Name;
    int amount;
}
```

If I have a list as `List<Account>` then how can I get the total amount from this list without using any loop like `for` or `foreach`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create a Stream of your accounts using [`stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#stream--), map that stream to the amount of each account using [`mapToInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) and sum the resulting `IntStream` using [`IntStream.sum()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#sum--).

```
List<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<>();
int totalAmount = accounts.stream().mapToInt(Account::getAmount).sum();
```

This code assumes that there is a getter `getAmount` for `amount`.

Comment: yes its int i updated my question

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using a third party library, there is `sumOfInt` available in [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/).  It returns a `long` instead of an `int`, so the possibility of an overflow is much less likely.

You can either use a static utility method on the [`Iterate`](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/8.1.0/org/eclipse/collections/impl/utility/Iterate.html) class which works with any `java.lang.Iterable` type as follows:

```
List<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<>();
long sum = Iterate.sumOfInt(accounts, Account::getAmount);
```

Or you if your list is a [`MutableList`](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/8.1.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/list/MutableList.html), you can use the method directly available on the list.

```
MutableList<Account> accounts = Lists.mutable.empty();
long sum = accounts.sumOfInt(Account::getAmount);
```

**Note:** I am a committer for Eclipse Collections

Comment: If one care about overflow, `.mapToLong(Account::getAmount).sum()` or `.collect(summingLong(Account::getAmount))` would work just as fine.